# Xamarin Visual Studio cannot launch Build Server Activation on networked MAC

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I’m having trouble getting my MAC to activate so that it can be a build server.
I have activated my trial subscription on my PC.
I have run the tutorial inside of Xamarin on the MAC (it’s a MacBook Air), and successfully deployed my ‘Hello World’ app to an iPad.

I am having problems getting things to work on my Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio.
I am going through the tutorial about ‘Hello World’ on in Visual Studio.
From Visual Studio, when I open a new ‘HelloWorld’ project for iPhone, it pops up the following dialog:

[image: Activation Dialog]

I click Activate, and get this:

[image: Activation Done Dialog]

However, nothing happens on the MAC.  No activation app starts up.  I opened the Console on the map to view any errors, and it has a brief message about a connection from my PC on a particular port, but it doesn’t seem to be an error message.

In the Output window of Visual Studio 2012 I get the following when pressing ‘Accept’ and ‘Done’ on the dialogs above:

[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6] Handling with command: [LaunchApplication: CommmandUrl=LaunchApplication] (9)
[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00
[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6] LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to determine the application with bundle identifier com.xamarin.monotouchactivation.
[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6] Error: Failed to launch : com.xamarin.monotouchactivation.
[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6]  Process Output 
[2013-07-05 13:36:12.6] Command [LaunchApplication: CommmandUrl=LaunchApplication] finished (9)
[2013-07-05 13:37:02.7] Handling with command: [Info: CommmandUrl=Info] (9)
[2013-07-05 13:37:02.7] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00
[2013-07-05 13:37:02.7] Starting /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --listdev
[2013-07-05 13:37:03.7] stdout: Charrison: 8d0c6bc55d4e353d50763906e9174afc6ea9777e
[2013-07-05 13:37:03.9] 
[2013-07-05 13:37:03.9] Starting /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --entitlements
[2013-07-05 13:37:04.2] stdout: 7fbe910742c6436e19454359a2175f6a5b7b1499 MonoTouch Starter 0001-01-01T00:00:00
[2013-07-05 13:37:04.4] 
[2013-07-05 13:37:04.4] Command [Info: CommmandUrl=Info] finished (9)

I’m guessing that ‘LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to determine the application with bundle identifier com.xamarin.monotouchactivation’ is what is wrong.

So, what is wrong here and how can I activate my MAC to be a build server?

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: for licensing issues contact support@xamarin.com

Comment: I had this problem before with a paid version. I was able to get the Xamarin.iOS to activate by going to Project->Profile-Mono menu in Xamarin Studio in my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see my post here http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4967/unable-to-activate-the-build-host

seems like you need to open an iOS project on the mac, then select Project -> Profile - Mono...

Then it seems to activate your product in some way.

Comment: Excellent !!  That did the trick for me.  Thank you very much Quincy!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer instead of a comment for maximum derp factor:

I had read [another post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4661/can-t-activate-on-mac) on the forums addressing this issue, and could not find the Project->Profile - Mono menu item UNTIL AFTER I had created a project (an empty iPhone one did the trick).